# Lasso Logistic Regression suitable for imbalanced data?

Tags: r-caret, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am analyzing the Secom dataset from the UCI Machine Learning repository by lasso-regularized logistic regression, but the results are bad.

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/SECOM

Characteristics:

- 1546 data samples with 590 numeric attributes
- 106 positive samples (production failures)

The goal is to predict the positive class accurately, and also to perform feature selection.

I optimize lambda by 10 fold cross validation with the glmnet package in R. But the results are terrible, as the model tends to assign all test samples to only a single class.

Is it simply the wrong kind of model for this dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Predicting with imbalanced classes can be a very difficult problem to solve. Thankfully, there is a huge bibliography on how to solve such problems. There is a particular one that worked really well for me. It involves using up-sampling and/or down-sampling techniques:

- down-sampling: randomly subset all the classes in the training set so that their class frequencies match the least prevalent class. For example, suppose that 80% of the training set samples are the first class and the remaining 20% are in the second class. Down-sampling would randomly sample the first class to be the same size as the second class (so that only 40% of the total training set is used to fit the model). caret contains a function (downSample) to do this.
- up-sampling: randomly sample (with replacement) the minority class to be the same size as the majority class. caret contains a function (upSample) to do this.
- hybrid methods: techniques such as SMOTE and ROSE down-sample the majority class and synthesize new data points in the minority class. There are two packages (DMwR and ROSE) that implement these procedures.

I took the above bullet points from this [caret's](https://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html) documentation. The post contains examples about each one of the above bullet points and R code. You should be able to use a Lasso logistic regression and have better results after you have transformed your data based on the above techniques.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.